# Ensuring Regularity of Time pieces

Tags: time, measurements

Physics defines, I'm told, that time is "whatever" the clock measures.  Time is a measurement means it has to have a *unit*. So let *s* (seconds) be the unit of time.

If time measurement is anything like, has to be like, *length measurement*, $1$ s = $(2 - 1)$ s = $((n + 1) - n)$ s. This is what we'd call *consistency* in *magnitude* aka *regular* in the sense $1$ tick = $1$ s always, everywhere, for anyone. It's, I believe, a simple notion in math/measurement.

So I have a clock $C_1$. I can't know that $C_1$ is *regular* using $C_1$. That would be like trying to check a newspaer $N$ for accuracy by reading $N$ (circulos in probando).

Ergo, we need another clock $C_2$ which must itself be *regular*. To check if $C_2$ is regular we need a $3^{rd}$ clock $C_3$, which itself has to be checked for regularity. So on and so forth ... *infinite regress*.

How does physics solve this problem if it is one?

Comment: _1  tick = 1 s always, everywhere, for anyone_. There's no absolute time, time passage depends on reference frame, so your "1 s" can be different than mine. Check time dilation in special relativity. So at core your question is doomed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We choose a standard that we are reasonably sure is constant. Specifically we can relate time to energy because for light waves the frequency of the light created by an electron transition in an atom is related to the energy of the transition by:

$$ f = \frac{E}{h} $$

Since the transition energy of an atom depends only on fundamental constants the frequency of the light cannot change unless the fundamental constants change. While it's possible that the fundamental constants could change, all the experiments done to check this have not detected any change and we have no reason from theoretical physics to suspect they can change. So we can be pretty confident that our frequency standard is reliable.

The standard we currently use is the [caesium standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesium_standard). This [defines the second](https://www.npl.co.uk/si-units/second) in a way we believe is reliable.

Comment: Gracias. Does calculating the apposite physical constants involve the use of a clock at any point? Any *rates* would mean a clock measurement. Also, most importantly, it would be really, really cool if we could calculate the frequency without the use of a clock!

Comment: The constants cannot be calculated. They have to be experimentally measured. But we don't need the constants to define the second. We just count 9192631770 oscillations of the light from the caesium atom and we define the time taken to be one second.

Comment: Intriguing that ($we - me$) *know* for *certain* that the oscillations are *regular* i.e. constant *periodicity*. Is that mathematically determined. I ask because all (?) of the large scale periodic phenomena (rotation/revolution of the earth/a planet/a moon/heartbeats, etc.) are *irregular*.

Comment: @AgentSmith we do not _know for certain_ that the light from the caesium atom is always the same frequency, but we believe it to be the case.

Comment: If (say), frequency is given by a function $f(x) = \frac {k_1x}{k_2x}$ where $k_1$ and $k_2$ are constants (measured clocklessly) then it *doesn't matter* whether a *clock* was part of the calculation of $x$, but it's rather odd that we can get a *unit* for time *without* a chronometer.

Comment: @AgentSmith You may enjoy browsing http://leapsecond.com/ "A web site dedicated to precise Time & Frequency [...] A man with one clock knows what time it is. A man with two clocks is never sure."

Comment: That's a good one! 

Comment: @AgentSmith Btw, your given "function" is not function at all but just ratio of constants $f(x) = \frac {k_1x}{k_2x} = \frac {k_1}{k_2} = const $ :-). But you are right to some degree. If you would like to validate current definition of time, you would have to use frequency counter of $Cs^{133}$ base transition for 1s. But, frequency counter must know a-priory what 1 second is. So cyclic definition. Older definition of $kg$ was similarly cyclic - 1 kg is "1 kg" sample stored in France. But you know what ? Physics don't deals with definitions in general, it's the are of philosophy. We measure.

Comment: $y = f(x) = k$ isn't a function? .